# sequelize datatypes.NOW function does not generate timestamp

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My code is as shown below:

```
  let time = db.Sequelize.DataTypes.NOW;

  console.log('generated time is' + time);
```

db.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
require('dotenv').config();


const db = {};


var sequelize = new Sequelize({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    username: process.env.DB_USER_NAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    dialect: process.env.DB_TYPE,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    },
    operatorsAliases: false
});

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('connected to database successfully')
    })


sequelize.sync({
    force: false
})


db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;
```

The output that I get is

```
generated time is  function NOW() {
  if (!(this instanceof NOW)) return new NOW();
}
```

How can I generate timestamp with value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's absolutely the right way how it should work. Why do you think, it should return a timestamp? It should not. If you'd like to get a `timestamp`, just run:

```
new Date().getTime()
```

Answer (score -1):

In Migration, you can use literal. This will help you, I  also face such problem. This works:

```
defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
```